# Update SET with variable column names, variable values in variable rows PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, set

I'm trying to update a certain column of certain row WHERE id is certain value. The thing is, the number/names of columns are variable, and so are their respective ids.

For example:

```
UPDATE table SET column1="hello" WHERE id = 5
UPDATE table SET column2="cucumber" WHERE id = 6
```

How can I do a single mysql query in PDO to do this?
First thing I tried is...

```
UPDATE table SET column1="hello", column4="bye" WHERE id IN(5, 6)
```

But that query will update BOTH of those columns in rows where it finds BOTH of those ids, and that's not what I'm looking for. Is it only possible to do this query by query?

Keep in mind that the argument after SET is variable, so the columns to be updated, their values and their respective ids are also variable.
A solution where you can just purely bind values would be great, but if I have to build the query string with escaped variables, then that's OK too.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you *want* to perform this update in a single query?  If it's atomicity that you're after, have you considered performing separate updates within a single transaction?

Comment: As in placing all required `UPDATE table SET ... WHERE ...` queries in a single query and building the transaction with a loop and strings?

Comment: As in `$pdo->beginTransaction();` followed by `$pdo->exec()` (or whatever you prefer) for each `UPDATE`; followed by `$pdo->commit()`.

Comment: Oh, cool, I had never read on that. Is it possible to bind values to each exec or do I need to build the query for each exec? Sorry if I come off as a complete noob.

Comment: You can't parameterise SQL object identifiers (such as column names), so in your case it looks like you will have to rebuild the SQL each time.

Comment: Great, I think I get it. I'm think I'm doing this, sounds less tangled than the solution below. What would be the benefit of doing it this way rather than the way presented in the solution below? My guess is that I can know the outcome of each query? (And apparently rollback?)

Comment: That's correct.  It's also likely to be more scaleable, since the situation below will suffer performance-wise as the table and/or number of updates increases.

Comment: Neat. Thank you, your advice was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2
    ON t1.id= 5 AND t2.id= 6
   SET t1.column1= 'hello',
       t2.column2 = 'cucumber';
```

Or if you want to do this on a single column

```
UPDATE table
   SET column2 = CASE id
                      WHEN 5 THEN 'hello' 
                      WHEN 6 THEN '' 
                      END
 WHERE id IN(5, 6);
```

Comment: So say I have 5 different columns to update in 5 different places... I would do...
`UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2, table t3, table t4, table t5
    ON t1.id= 5 AND t2.id= 6 AND t3.id=3 AND t4.id=10 AND t5.id=1534
   SET t1.column1= 'hello',
       t3.column24 = 'cucumber',
       t4.column22 = 'melon',
       t5.column21 = 'hairdryer';`
? Hmm, that looks probably as complex as declaring each UPDATE SET.

Comment: This works as a solution. Whoever might read this in the future, with a situation similar to mine: you may also want to look at the question's comments.